# Cloud Run, after set up Load Balancer Web page can`t be open

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection abc.net uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

I followed https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip

and I followed https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setup-global-ext-https-serverless

and I got above error

my web domain site is not working at all currently.

```
abc-cdnloadbalancer HTTP(S) HTTP         1 backend bucket       
abc-balancer    HTTP(S) HTTPS        1 backend service (0 instance groups, 1 network endpoint group)
```

What's very strange about the second document is that I already made a cdn balancer according to the document when assigning a static ip. But I was told to make another balancer, so I made it again.

Comment: I believe this is the same concern in your previous post from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74192070/cloud-run-after-set-fixed-static-ip-cloud-flare-not-working) right? Please delete the old post since this one has more details to avoid confusion with other users which post that they are going to answer.

Comment: @YvanG. I`m afraid I believe this is dfferent at all

Comment: I see, can you answer my comment from your previous post since you mentioned it is different from this post. May I also know if this is a different cloud run that is not working due to changes. Do you have 2 cloud run deployed in your account?

Comment: @YvanG. yah when I delete the load balancer, then it works again

Comment: Im confused about creating another load balancer, can you share which part of the document shows will create another load balancer?

Regarding your concern have you checked this part of the [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setup-global-ext-https-serverless#update_dns) Once you create a load balancer it will generate a new IP address, once your load balancer is associated with your cloud run you need to update your DNS server “A record” and place it in the IP address of the load balancer. Also, consider the propagation once A record is changed.

Comment: @YvanG. When you are assigned a static IP, you must complete the dns server mapping in the first place. and that would be https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip. and I wanted to add load balancer so I checked out the load balancer docuements, and that would be https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setup-global-ext-https-serverless. But when I tried to do the second one, the cdn loadbalancer I did the first time already existed. So I am confused right now

Comment: I understand, because the traffic will route at the static IP address that is why it is needed to map in your DNS. But once you configured Load balancer, the traffic will now route at the load balancer that is why the IP address should be the IP address of the load balancer.

There is no need to create two load balancer and I believe there are no statement in the documentation that you need to create two load balancer, once you create https load balancer there is already an option to enable cloud cdn. Did you create cloud cdn then create an https load balancer?

Comment: @YvanG. Thanks for answering! Now I doubt perhaps the name called "cdn-loadbalancer"(in my gcp) is from GCS.. it could be.. I thought it was created while creating a static ip because it already exists when I go to the load balancing page .. (but it may still be I am not sure) shoot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual use of [Static Outbound IP Address](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) is to have an outbound traffic from your Cloud run. Now, if your only goal by having a Static Outbound IP Address is to have an access in your domain hosted by Cloud Run then my advice will be to disregard the Static Outbound IP Address.

The http(s) Load Balancer can also have an access in your domain hosted by Cloud Run and at the same time by creating [http(s) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setup-global-ext-https-serverless) there is an option to enable CDN where you can under backend configuration. Just make sure after creating Load Balancer the next configuration will be connecting your domain to your load balancer as stated in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setup-global-ext-https-serverless#update_dns)

It will all depend on your goal for this setup.